# How can I generate an F# map as I process a tree using recursion in an idiomatic way

Tags: recursion, dictionary, f#, immutability

I'm trying to convert a sequence of paths into a single tree structure for saving in a pre-determined format. A single path is defined as a string list. I'm struggling to create the final set/map of tree nodes before saving them. The code I have so far looks like this below. Note the mutable collection of nodes.

How can I remove the mutability and get the same result? Have I structured this correctly or am I going off in the wrong direction? I'm fairly new to F# from many years as a C# dev.

```
type Node = {
    Name: string
    Parent: Node option
    }

let mutable collection = Map.empty

let find parent name =
    let key = (parent, name)

    if collection.ContainsKey key then
        collection.Item key
    else
        let node = { Name = name; Parent = parent; }
        collection <- collection.Add(key, node)
        node

let parse path =
    let rec gather parent nodes =
        match parent with
        | None -> nodes
        | Some p -> gather p.Parent (p :: nodes)

    let rec parserec parent path = 
        match path with 
        | [] -> gather parent []
        | head :: tail ->
            let parent = Some (find parent head)
            parserec parent tail
    parserec None path

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let paths = seq {
        yield ["A"; "B"; "D"; "E"]
        yield ["A"; "B"; "D"; "F"]
        yield ["A"; "B"; "D"; "G"]
        yield ["A"; "C"; "D"; "G"]
        }

    let result =
        paths
        |> Seq.map parse
        |> Seq.toList

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

An alternative set of paths might be:

```
let paths = seq {
    yield ["C:"; "Program Files"; "Common"; "Oracle"]
    yield ["C:"; "Program Files"; "Common"; "IBM"]
    yield ["C:"; "Program Files"; "Common"; "Microsoft"]
    yield ["C:"; "Windows"; "Common"; "Microsoft"]
    }
```

and I expect to generate a set of nodes equivalent to this tree:

```
C:
    Program Files
        Common
            Oracle
            IBM
            Microsoft
    Windows
        Common
            Microsoft
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the Map? If you remove it and leave the else branch you get the same results.

Comment: @Gustavo if you remove the map then you end up with 16 node instances instead of 9.

Comment: I did a compare and I get exactly the same result. Anyway, isn't it better to generate something like type Node = {
    Name  : string
    Childs: Node list
    } ?

Comment: I would like to but I couldn't work out how to do it with immutable structures. I'd love you see your implementation as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments I would rather define node as `{Name: string; Childs: Node list}` since usually a tree is to be traversed from root to branches.

Here's  a possible solution:

```
type Node = {
    Name  : string
    Childs: Node list}

let rec genNodes nodes ls =
    match (nodes, ls) with
    | (n , []   ) -> n
    | ([], x::xs) -> [{Name = x; Childs = genNodes [] xs}]
    | ({Name = nm; Childs = ch}::ns, x::xs) ->
        if nm = x then {Name = nm; Childs = genNodes ch xs}::ns
        else           {Name = nm; Childs = ch}::genNodes ns ls

// Test

let paths = seq {
    yield ["A"; "B"; "D"; "E"]
    yield ["A"; "B"; "D"; "F"]
    yield ["A"; "B"; "D"; "G"]
    yield ["A"; "C"; "D"; "G"]
    }

let result = Seq.fold genNodes [] paths
```

In this recursive solution there is no mutability and the 'find' is automatically performed by falling to the right case of the match.

Comment: Am I missing something? I've just compiled and run this and it doesn't work. The last branch of the match is never hit.

Comment: May be you have changed something without noticing it. If you run the code as it is in F# interactive it works perfectly. Check the indents. As you can see by following the code the last part of the match should be hit each time both lists are not empty.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what your algorithm is doing, but removing mutation is fairly straightforward process. When you have a function that needs to "mutate" the `collection` variable, you can change it so that it returns `collection` as part of the result. So, for example your original version of `find`:

```
let find parent name =
  let key = (parent, name)
  if collection.ContainsKey key then
    collection.Item key
  else
    let node = { Name = name; Parent = parent; }
    collection <- collection.Add(key, node)
    node
```

The original function mutates `collection` and then it returns the `node` found. You can change it so that it returns a tuple consisting of the new `collection` value *together* with the node. To keep the track of the current state, it also needs to take `collection` as input:

```
let find (collection:Map<_, _>) parent name =
  let key = (parent, name)
  if collection.ContainsKey key then
    collection, collection.Item key // Return a pair with collection and node
  else
    let node = { Name = name; Parent = parent; }
    collection.Add(key, node), node // Return newly extended collection & node
```

Changing the rest of the code follows the same principle - add `collection` as a parameter and return the new state as the result.

Comment: Thanks. Have added some additional bits about what I'm trying to achieve in case there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Code with Tomas' solution applied. Also realised I didn't need the gather function as returning the map is enough.

```
type Node = {
    Name: string
    Parent: Node option
    }

let parse (collection:Map<_, _>) path =
    let find (collection:Map<_, _>) parent name =
        let key = (parent, name)

        if collection.ContainsKey key then
            collection, collection.Item key
        else
            let node = { Name = name; Parent = parent; }
            collection.Add(key, node), node

    let rec parserec (collection:Map<_, _>) parent path = 
        match path with 
        | [] -> collection
        | head :: tail ->
            let collection, parent = find collection parent head
            parserec collection (Some parent) tail

    parserec collection None path

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let paths = seq {
        yield ["C:"; "Program Files"; "Common"; "Oracle"]
        yield ["C:"; "Program Files"; "Common"; "IBM"]
        yield ["C:"; "Program Files"; "Common"; "Microsoft"]
        yield ["C:"; "Windows"; "Common"; "Microsoft"]
        }

    let result =
        paths
        |> Seq.fold parse Map.empty
        |> Seq.toList

    0
```